# How to position element in action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, action

I am not able to align element in action bar.Can someone please help me out with the issue.I want to align image on the left corner and title in the middle and one setting option in the right corner.There is one arrow to go back on other activity .I want to remove that option.Please refer the screen shot for more info.

ActionBar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/pic13"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_profile);
    final ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();
    abar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.title));//line under the action bar
    View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.abs_layout, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView textviewTitle = (TextView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_textview);
    textviewTitle.setText("Test");
    abar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
    abar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    abar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    abar.setIcon(R.drawable.pic13);
    abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

[image]

Comment: instead of android:layout_gravity use android:gravity

Comment: @helldawg Thanks for the reply .But it is not working.I want to remove the arrow and place the image on that place.

Comment: The arrow is shown because you have `abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: @cricket_007 I have removed that line still I am getting that arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code to your xml

**Toolbar is a ViewGroup, you can customize is as much as you want.**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Sorry.I had used this in wrong way.It is working fine and it is very easy to customize.

Comment: glad i could help.